# Replacing Golang standard package and calling the original within

Tags: go

Assume that there is a special hardware that can make
certain standard library functionality faster.

Hardware might be present or not.

I can write a package that would utilize this hardware with the same 
function signatures as in the standard one, but it will force all the applications and other packages to decide which package to import based on the availability of the hardware on the specific target. At build time and with code modifications in all the applications and packages.

Ideally, I would prefer to make the decision of which package to use at runtime and without requiring applications to change their imports.

The package would check for the availability of the hardware and would either use it or execute standard functionality instead.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Any other ways to "intercept" the calls to the standard package functions?

Comment: Do you mean injection or hook into the binary code like JIT?

Comment: Your question deserves votes to close for this reason: "Too broad: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer." For example, do you want Intel SSE4? Do you want ARM floating point? Or what?

Comment: @peterSO I don't think that detail matters, OP just wants to know what the mechanism is for doing it. The mechanism has little to do with what specific hardware you're targeting.

Comment: @Adrian: It matters.

Comment: @peterSO care to explain that?

Comment: The hardware shouldn't matter here. Think about LD_PRELOAD and how libraries like JEMALLOC "hijack" all the memory allocation calls without requiring the changes in the applications. With static apps LD_PRELOAD is obviously not an option, so I am looking for other alternative ways that might be possible in Go.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're talking about a library that will be used by other applications. You can't (thankfully!) modify the standard library this way - otherwise just importing a package could have incredibly broad and potentially disastrous side-effects. If you want to apply some special hardware-specific optimizations to the standard library, for use by other people in a broad range of projects, your best bet is to [make your changes to the standard library and submit a patch](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: The hardware is not generic enough to justify inclusion in the standard lib. However, it provides valuable improvement to those who have it. The problem is that there are many other libraries that sit between the piece that I am improving and the actual application. Some of those would be application specific. Changing all of them by the application writer is complicated. That's why I am trying to see whether there is a way to "hook" in between. Think about LD_PRELOAD and how alternative memory heap managers hook in without requiring application writers to change all of their malloc calls.

Comment: There is not. LD_PRELOAD is based on shared libraries, while the Go stdlib is statically linked into the final binary.

Comment: It's clear that LD_PRELOAD can't work here due to static linking. The question is whether there is any other mechanism, build or runtime, that would allow interception of the calls to the specific standard library without changing all the other libraries that use it. It doesn't have to be completely transparent to the application writer, might require additional steps, just shouldn't require deep changes in everything that uses this specific standard library.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, and the answer is no, there is not any such mechanism. If you don't want to submit your changes to the Go team, you could fork Go and have your app devs use the fork, but then you have to keep up with upstream changes etc., plus that's a pretty hefty requirement for the devs using your changes.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I hoped for a different answer, but this is what it is.